# How to show a loader until images are ready then show them

Tags: image, loader

I am currently working on a website (http://thibaudjourdan.fr/). In the galleries, when your computer loads an image, it actually loads on the left of my screen and, once fully loaded, displays on the center like it should. I don't like this, is there a way to show some sort of loader instead of the image then show it once it's ready ?

I have seen some solutions on the internet but none seemed to fit my needs or i wouldn't get it to work, can anyone help ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is an onload event for images. That can be used to show it when its done

```
<img src="/path/to/image.jpg" onload="doStuff(this);" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also manage from jQuery

```
 $("img").one("load", function() {
  // do stuff
})
```